# .NET MVC application with Oracle database credentials changed

Tags: .net, oracle, model-view-controller

i have a .NET MVC web application using oracle database.  the application is in production and i have changed the credentials of the oracle db.  now i am not able to connect my application. anyone know where to change the oracle db password so that my .net application works

Answer (score 0):

Hi typically the best practice is to place database credentials in a connection string variable the web.config

Do you see anything there?

Another option is to search (ctrl+f) for the old.password name.in in your entire.solition and see if old password found unless its hashed.

If those two options fail to turn up.anything try search for the database server and seeing if connection.open or a password string is near by

Comment: i do not have solution. i am trying this from production. Is web.config file available in production

Comment: yes generally its included in the bin folder with the compiled aspnet dll